# How to subscribe to other class' events in C#?

Tags: c#, events, .net-2.0, event-handling

A simple scenario: a custom class that raises an event. I wish to consume this event inside a form and react to it.

How do I do that?

Note that the form and custom class are separate classes.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
public class EventThrower
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args) ;
    public event EventHandler ThrowEvent = delegate{};

    public void SomethingHappened() => ThrowEvent(this, new EventArgs());
}

public class EventSubscriber
{
    private EventThrower _Thrower;

    public EventSubscriber()
    {
        _Thrower = new EventThrower();
        // using lambda expression..could use method like other answers on here

        _Thrower.ThrowEvent += (sender, args) => { DoSomething(); };
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
       // Handle event.....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a great solution. I have figured it out right after I posted a question, and my solution is very similar to yours.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335131/winform-events-in-another-class-net2-simplify-delegate  for an implementation in .NET2

Comment: @CSgarpAtl I see this is selected as the correct answer. Unfortunately I cannot get it to work even though I have followed every step. I'm trying to make my main form aware of the method that has happened in my User Control.

Comment: +1, This still is a valid approach in a one publisher/none-to-many-subscriber situation.  Decoupling is increased when the publisher doesn't need to know about the subscribers.  A few modifications are needed to apply the solution to static classes, but the basic idea is the same.  Subscribe to the publisher event from the subscriber class through a reference to the publisher instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 7):

Inside your form:

```
private void SubscribeToEvent(OtherClass theInstance) => theInstance.SomeEvent += this.MyEventHandler;

private void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Do something on the event
}
```

You just subscribe to the event on the other class the same way you would to an event in your form.  The three important things to remember:

1. You need to make sure your method (event handler) has the appropriate declaration to match up with the delegate type of the event on the other class.
2. The event on the other class needs to be visible to you (ie: public or internal).
3. Subscribe on a valid instance of the class, not the class itself.

Comment: @Reed_Copsey Can oyu provide some more code, somehow my event will not be accepted by the handler

Comment: @Gobliins I don't know what your issue is - I would recommend asking your own question with full details.

Comment: Its the same issue as the topic, but nvm i already solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your event is handled by EventHandler, this code works:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myObj = new MyClass();
    myObj.MyEvent += new EventHandler(this.HandleCustomEvent);
}

private void HandleCustomEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // handle the event
}
```

If your "custom event" requires some other signature to handle, you'll need to use that one instead.