# WinForm event subscription to another class

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private EventThrower _Thrower;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It worked");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Thrower = new EventThrower();
        //using lambda expression..need to use .NET2 so can't use this.
        _Thrower.ThrowEvent += (sender2, args) => { DoSomething(); };

        var eventThrower = new EventThrower();
        eventThrower.test();
    }
}

public class EventThrower
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
    public event EventHandler ThrowEvent = delegate { };

    public void SomethingHappened()
    {
        ThrowEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public void test()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        SomethingHappened();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get my winform UI to subscribe to an event in EventThrower class.  DoSomething never fires.

[How to subscribe to other class' events in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913374/how-to-subscribe-to-other-class-events-in-c)

Comment: Try `_Thrower.test();` instead of making another EventThrower()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you create a new EventThrower before calling test.

If you change:

```
    var eventThrower = new EventThrower();
    eventThrower.test();
```

to:

```
    _Thrower.test();
```

It will call DoSomething.

Comment: Lame... I answered 10 seconds before you :D

Answer (score 1):

The event is not static, one instance of the `EventHandler` exists for *each instance* of `EventThrower`.

You subscribe to the event on `_Thrower`, yet you create a new instance of `EventThrower` and call `test()` on *that instance*.  You never subscribed to the event on that instance, so your handler doesn't run.

It should be:

```
_Thrower.ThrowEvent += (sender2, args) => { DoSomething(); };
_Thrower.test();
```

Comment: Thanks to all.. have asked a follow up question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335131/winform-events-in-another-class-net2-simplify-delegate  which is different in that am going to .NET2 and trying to simplify.