# WinForm events in another class .NET2 Simplify delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Any way to make this working code simpler ie the delegate { }?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private CodeDevice codeDevice;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        codeDevice = new CodeDevice();

        //subscribe to CodeDevice.ConnectionSuccessEvent and call Form1.SetupDeviceForConnectionSuccessSate when it fires
        codeDevice.ConnectionSuccessEvent += new EventHandler(SetupDeviceForConnectionSuccessState);
    }

    private void SetupDeviceForConnectionSuccessState(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It worked");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        codeDevice.test();
    }
}

public class CodeDevice
{
    public event EventHandler ConnectionSuccessEvent = delegate { };

    public void ConnectionSuccess()
    {
        ConnectionSuccessEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public void test()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ConnectionSuccess();
    }
}
```

[WinForm event subscription to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334661/winform-event-subscription-to-another-class)

[How to subscribe to other class' events in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913374/how-to-subscribe-to-other-class-events-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If don't think you could simplyfy:

```
public event EventHandler ConnectionSuccessEvent = delegate { }
```

even in c#3 + you could only do

```
public event EventHandler ConnectionSuccessEvent = () => { }
```

However you could simplify

```
codeDevice.ConnectionSuccessEvent += new EventHandler(SetupDeviceForConnectionSuccessState);
```

to

```
codeDevice.ConnectionSuccessEvent += SetupDeviceForConnectionSuccessState;
```

Comment: Thank you @Ben - just tried another one which is ConnectionSuccess(null,null) as I'm not using the object, not the args.  However will keen as above for now.

Comment: The problem with ConnectionSuccess(null,null) is that you have add the assumption that sender or the eventargs will never be referenced.  Another developer might write a method that subcribed to this event and used these params which would then cause a null reference exception.  `ConnectionSuccessEvent(this, new EventArgs());` or `ConnectionSuccessEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);` are better.