# how to raise event in all the object of my class?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, methods, raiseevent

I have C# class for which I am creating multiple objects for that class.

Now, I have one event for which all the objects of that class needs perform operation(In other words, I need to call specific function of all the object for that event).

The event is external to class.

Event is caused when I receive data from some external input in other class B or class C and I have to send that data to all the object of class A using method or event.

I need to raise event from multiple class B/C/D in class A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subscribe to other class' events in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913374/how-to-subscribe-to-other-class-events-in-c)

Comment: @Sylverac , Thanks for link but I need to raise event from multiple classes to single class. !!

Comment: @H.Mahida - Can you please show the code that you currently have for your object and for the code that raises the external event?

Answer (score 2):

A modern, clean way to handle this would be to use Reactive Extensions.

Suppose your event argument is of type `EArg`.

Place a static `Subject<EArg>` in your class A.

```
private static readonly Subject<EArg> subject = new Subject<EArg>();
```

Each instance of A can observe this `IObservable<T>` and act on it.

```
public ClassA()    // Constructor
{
   subject.Subscribe(HandleEvent);
}

private void HandleEvent(EArg arg)
{
   // ... 
}
```

When any external class calls (perhaps via a static method on class A) the `OnNext` method, all of the instances of class A can respond to it.

```
public static void RaiseEvent(EArg arg)
{
   subject.OnNext(arg);
}
```

Essentially you are looking for a pub-sub mechanism and Reactive Extensions is the cleanest way to achieve that.

NB, don't expose the `Subject` externally, see for example [Why are Subjects not recommended in .NET Reactive Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396449/why-are-subjects-not-recommended-in-net-reactive-extensions)

Comment: I totally agree than Rx is an excellent fit here, but your answer is a bit confusing and not overly convincing. I think you should explain the relationship between `Subject<T>` and `IObservable<T>`, and also provide some sample code to show how it would work for the OP.

Comment: Maybe, but let's see what the OP says. We really more information about what the event arguments are in order to define the appropriate Subject.