# Passing Continuous data from one XAML page to another Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-10-universal

I am trying to take data that i am reading from a serial device on one xaml page and pass it to another. I can get the data to go to the other page but not continuously. Meaning for example, if i were to use a textchanged event, the data comes through from the first page but only once. This could be because the data does not change all the time? Sometimes the save value is read multiple times before changing. However i have also simulated with the data constantly changing and still the event only fires once. I am currently storing a string value in the app.xaml.cs from the main page then reading it from the second page. I have also tried with a static class and they both have same results. Im sure its a simple fix but i cant figure it out. Any help appreciated.

On the main page i have this.

```
  App app = Application.Current as App;
  app.readData = rotAngle.ToString("F2");
```

and this on the next page

```
  private void rawValText_DataContextChanged(FrameworkElement sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
    {            
        App app = Application.Current as App;
        rawValText.Text = app.readData;
    }
```

but it only fires once when the page loads.

Comment: Probably need to add some sort of code to demonstrate. I think that you should use MVVM if you have frequent data changes that need to reflect on the view and/or inform another class.

Comment: added some code. -thanks

Comment: Where is your textchanged event?

Comment: I have it as a text block right now so using DataContextChangedEvent

Answer (score 0):

Use events. Use static class for this.

Fire event when data is recieved in Page1.

Write event handler in Page2 to receive event fired from Page1.

Simple !

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried that but event only fires once. I need it to fire continuously

Comment: The two pages are active all the time in 2 separate frames ?

Comment: Only the first page. The second is only active while you're on it

Comment: When it is not actice how you are expecting it participate in event handling

Comment: I'm not. Only when the second page is active.

Comment: u want Page1 to send data only when Page2 is active ?

Comment: Correct. And it does but only once.

Comment: handle Loaded event of Page2, plugin your event-handler. there must be some simple mistake on your side.

Comment: I'll recheck in the morning. My eyes hurt:/ thanks for all the help. I'll post what I find tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using DataContextChangedEvent incorrectly. DataContextChangedEvent fires when the DataContext changes. You should use the appropriate Event. You could either look up MVVM and use INotifyPropertyChanged, or you can keep your way and subscribe to an event on the other page, which you notify from the other:

[How to subscribe to other class' events in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913374/how-to-subscribe-to-other-class-events-in-c)

Essentially you have to code the notification yourself.

EDIT: Sample MVVM Tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute

Comment: Ok I'll look into it. Is there an advantage over one way or the other?

Comment: I would use MVVM simply because it's cleaner, and it's easier to deal with UI stuff (no threading issues, etc), but then there's a lot of XAML involved. Plus if you've already finished your app using codebehind (i.e. what you're doing) you wouldn't want to redo it I guess.

Comment: Actually, seeing that you're targetting Windows 10 universal, MVVM would be the best choice.

Comment: Ah ok I see. I will look into this and try to implement tomorrow. Thank you. I'll update you on results.