# Handling events across different classes using C#

Tags: wpf, events

I have a property defined in Class A. When the property is changed then i need to raise an event. Another class B should respond to this event and do something. I have done something like this:

Code:

```
Class A{
string variable = "test";
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
public static event EventHandler ThrowAddEvent = delegate { };
public static event EventHandler ThrowRemoveEvent = delegate { };
public String Name { get; set; }
public int Select { get; set; }
public Window Formref1 { get; set; } 
 public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return IsSlctd; }
        set
        {
            IsSlctd = value;
            if (value)
            {
                ThrowAddEvent(this, new EventArgs());

            }

            else
            {
                ThrowRemoveEvent(this, new EventArgs());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Another class which is responding to this event is defined as follows:

```
Class B{
 public B(ParsedResult _result)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (_result != null)
        {
            this.Result = _result;
            PopulateColumns1();
            DataGrid1.Items.Clear();
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = Populatevariables();

        }
    }
 public void PopulateColumns1()
    {
        DataGridTextColumn Colvar = new DataGridTextColumn();
        Colvar.Header = "Variables";
        Colvar.Binding = new Binding("Name");
        DataGrid1.Columns.Add(Colvar);

         DataGridTemplateColumn Col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();


        Col.Header = "Select";

        DataTemplate dd = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory FF = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
        FF.SetBinding(CheckBox.BindingGroupProperty, new Binding("Select"));
        FF.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("IsSelected") { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
        FF.SetValue(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);


        dd.VisualTree = FF;
        Col.CellTemplate = dd;

        DataGrid1.Columns.Add(Col);
    }

private List<A> PopulateVariables()
    {

        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        List<A> CharList = new List<A>();
        Result.GetCharacteristicList.MoveNext();
        IEnumerator<A2LCharacteristic> enumeratorlist = Result.GetCharacteristicList;
        for (int i = 0; enumeratorlist.MoveNext(); i++)
        {
            CharList.Add(new A() { Name = enumeratorlist.Current.Name,  Select = i, Formref1 = this});

        }


        enumeratorlist.Reset();
        return CharList;
    }
private void OKBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        A Instance_A = new A();

        Instance_A.ThrowAddEvent += (sender1, args) => { Addvrbl(Instance_A.variable); };

        Instance_A.ThrowRemoveEvent += (sender2, args) => { RmvVrbl(Instance_A.variable); };
        this.Close();
    }

 public void Addvrbl(string vrbl)
    {
        if (!(vrbllist.Contains(vrbl)))
        {
            vrbllist.Add(vrbl);
        }
    }

    public void RmvVrbl(string vrbl)
    {
        if ((vrbllist.Contains(vrbl)))
        {
            vrbllist.Remove(vrbl);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it is not going inside the method "AddVrbl" and "RmvVrbl". I have used the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913374/how-to-subscribe-to-other-class-events-in-c). Please help.

Comment: Make sure you have subscribed to the correct instance of A.

Comment: What exactly you meant by that?

Comment: In your Class `B`, you are subscribing to the events of `new A()`, is this `new A()` the same instance that bind to your view and publish events?

Comment: Can you please suggest how to make sure that both the instances are same. Currently class A is a row helper class containing only properties and events which will be set by Class B.

Comment: I have also tried by defining all the events "Static" but it did not serve the purpose.

Comment: Where did you use the ClassA, how did you bind it to the view (XAML), show the XAML code.

Comment: Thanks :) I have edited my code. Can you please have a look now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, instead of subscribing to the event of a new instance of A,which will never get triggered/published. When you initializing `CharList`, you have to subscribe to the event of each `A` item.

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; enumeratorlist.MoveNext(); i++)
{
     var obja=new A() { Name = enumeratorlist.Current.Name, Select = i, Formref1 = this};
     obja.ThrowAddEvent += ...
     obja.ThrowRemoveEvent += ...
     CharList.Add(obja);    
}
```

PS: Make sure you un-subscribe these events before removing an item from your `CharList`.

Comment: can you please answer one more question. The link is (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696178/how-to-display-items-in-data-grid-view-based-on-many-checkbox-selection-in-wpf)