# Find when something on form has been clicked

Tags: c#, click

I know that I can check when an item has been clicked or not.

But if I have an `_Click` event on my `Widget`, when this event is triggered, can I trigger the `_click` event for my form as well?

I have used a `pictureBox` in my class and I wrote the code for it inside my class and now I do not know how to register a click on my form as well.

EDIT: I'm sorry; it was a clumsy explanaiton
I'll try again: How can I throw an `Event` (or something like that) in my class and catch it in a `Form`?

Comment: It may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247946/handling-a-click-for-all-controls-on-a-form, but `code for it inside my class and now I do not know how to register a click on my form` part may suggest something different, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913374/how-to-subscribe-to-other-class-events-in-c. So it is not fully clear what you want to achieve and what the issue is  - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `Form.OnClick` to simulate a click on the Form. On my example I created a button and added a Click event to it. When the button is clicked, it simulates a Click on the Form, which triggers the Form's Click event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // do something when it's clicked
    this.OnClick(new EventArgs());
}

private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("a click occurred on the form");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with **wndproc**