# How to invoke different methods/scripts from one delegate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, delegates, invoke

I'm trying to understand my question. 
I have a server object in Unity scene. 
The server needs to invoke different methods from different scenes each time a message from Client arrives.

I'd prefer not to keep references to all the interaction scripts in my scene within the Server script. My solution was to create a delegate and have the interaction script subscribe to the delegate event. However my scene has changed and I find that two methods from different scripts subscribe to the same delegate and I get only on good outcome.

My solution was to create another delegate specifically to the next method but I wonder how many delegates can I create and is there a way to create one delegate but have it execute another function each time (or is it another action?)

```
public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void CommunicationEvent();
    public static event CommunicationEvent OnCommunication;

    public delegate void PortalEvent();
    public static event PortalEvent OnSceneSync;

    private const int MAX_USER = 1;
    private const int PORT = 26000;
    private const int WEB_PORT = 26001;
    private const int BYTE_SIZE = 1024; 

 /*.... */

    private void LightsOn(int cnnId, int recHostId, Net_OnEnterGate oeg)
    {
        OnCommunication?.Invoke();
        SendClient(recHostId, cnnId, oeg);
    }

    private void SceneSyncing(int cnnId, int recHostId, Net_OnSceneSync oss)
    {
        oss.TransNumber = LoadScene.currentSceneNumber;
        OnSceneSync?.Invoke();
        SendClient(cnnId, recHostId, oss);
    }

    private void LoadNewScene(int cnnID, int recHostId, Net_OnSceneLoad osl)
    {
        OnCommunication?.Invoke();
    }
```

I want if its possible to have one delegate OnCommunication(), and have different scripts subscribe to it to execute their unique methods and not execute the method from the previous script that in the scene.

Is it possible and what work flow would you suggest?

Comment: How do you subscripe to the `OnCommunication`?

Comment: This would be the normal used of [`.NET Events`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subscribe to other class' events in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913374/how-to-subscribe-to-other-class-events-in-c)

Comment: @Eliasar I'm not sure of the duplicate ... I don't even get the question completely yet ;)

Comment: Is your question basically how to add multiple "listeners" but execute only one of them each time?

Comment: @derHugo Right. I think OP should clarify who the message sender is (event invoker) and who the executor is (event handler). If the server is attempting to react when a client connects with their scene, the client needs to create the event and raise when connected. The arguments of the event handler call can be a Lambda or other delegate function.

Comment: Id like to review your answers and update soon

Comment: My issue was that I get a cue from the client to server, the server invokes a delegate and then the class invokes a subscribed method. The first time it works well, the class invokes a subscribed method for example "enter player". On the next cue the server invokes the same delegate but I want other class to subscribe to it, for example "open lights". Instead I get "enter player" again. Maybe one of the solutions is unsubscribing first in Awake function or have a list of the interface (as the 2 solution) by @derHugo. Also maybe the "possible duplicate" comment is a good solution

Comment: @Eliasar hello, I think the solution in the link you've passed maybe good for me. So basically I can differentiate between the delegate that is being called based on different sender or EventArg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question yet and don't see where you subscripe the callbacks to the events.

> I wonder how many delegates can I create

→ As many as you like! The question is do you need and do you want to?

---

If you want to add multiple callbacks to one event (that's how the title sounds) you simply use `+=` instead of `=`

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
     private void Awake()
     {
         // Note: It is always save to remove callbacks
         //       even if not added yet.
         //       This makes sure they are added only once for this instance
         OnCommunication -= OnServerCommunication;
         OnSceneSync -= OnServerSceneSync;

         OnCommunication += OnServerCommunication;
         OnSceneSync += OnServerSceneSync;
     }

     privtae void OnDestroy()
     {
         // Make sure to always remove callbacks when not needed anymore
         OnCommunication -= OnServerCommunication; 
         OnSceneSync -= OnServerSceneSync;
     }

     private void OnServerCommunication()
     {
         Debug.Log("Communication was invoked", this);
     }

     private void OnServerSceneSync()
     {
         Debug.Log("Scene sync was invoked", this);
     }
}
```

---

If your question is rather like "I want to add multiple callbacks but execute always only one of them." I would suggest to not use `event`s at all but something like

```
public interface IServerCommunicationHandler
{
    void OnServerCommunication();
}

public interface IServerSceneSyncHandler
{
    void OnServerSceneSync();
}
```

And in the server store listeners like

```
public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static readonly List<IServerCommunicationHandler> CommunicationListeners = new List<IServerCommunicationHandler>();
    private static readonly List<IServerSceneSyncHandler> SceneSyncListeners = new List<IServerSceneSyncHandler>();

    public static void AddCommunicationListener(IServerCommunicationHandler listener)
    {
        if (!CommunicationListeners.Contains(listener)) CommunicationListeners.Add(listener);
    }

    public static void RemoveCommunicationListener(IServerCommunicationHandler listener)
    {
        if (CommunicationListeners.Contains(listener)) CommunicationListeners.Remove(listener);
    }

    public static void AddSceneSyncListener(IServerSceneSyncHandler listener)
    {
        if (!SceneSyncListeners.Contains(listener)) SceneSyncListeners.Add(listener);
    }

    public static void RemoveSceneSyncListener(IServerSceneSyncHandler listener)
    {
        if (SceneSyncListeners.Contains(listener)) SceneSyncListeners.Remove(listener);
    }
}
```

and than instead of `OnCommunication?Invoke()` and `OnSceneSync?.Invoke()` have e.g.

```
private void InvokeCommunication()
{
    var listener = CommunicationListeners.Count > 0 ? CommunicationListeners[0] : null;
    if (listener == null) return;

    listener.OnServerCommunication();
    CommunicationListeners.RemoveAt(0);
}

private void InvokeSceneSync()
{
    var listener = SceneSyncListeners.Count > 0 ? SceneSyncListeners[0] : null;
    if (listener == null) return;

    listener.OnServerSceneSync();
    SceneSyncListeners.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Then the scripts could look like e.g.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IServerCommunicationHandler, IServerSceneSyncHandler
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        Server.AddCommunicationListener(this);
        Server.AddSceneSyncListener(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Server.RemoveCommunicationListener(this);
        Server.RemoveSceneSyncListener(this);
    }

    public void OnSeverCommunication()
    {
        Debug.Log("Communication was invoked", this);
    }

    public void OnServerSceneSync()
    {
        Debug.Log("Scene sync was invoked", this);
    }
}
```